# Unable to load PKCS11 driver using IAIK PKCS11 Wrapper

Tags: java, java-native-interface, pki, pkcs#11, iaik-jce

I'm using the following:

- Windows 7 64bit
- JDK 7 64bit
- JRE 7 64bit

The new funny JRE 7 64bit doesn't support Sun PKCS11 anymore (which is inside package 'sun.security.pkcs11'). And the big problem is that the end-users of the product by our company may have installed whatever version of JRE.

So I have to swap up the existing to code in 'Sun PKCS11' to '[IAIK PKCS11 Wrapper](http://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/sic/Products/Core-Crypto-Toolkits/PKCS_11_Wrapper)'. The wrapper by IAIK works simply this way:

```
(iaik-wrapper.jar)->(iaik-pkcs11-jni.dll)->(pki-token-driver.dll)
```

The PKI token driver dynamic link library is provided by the manufacturer of PKI USB token, it has the actual name of 'ca2-v34.dll'. The method to load this native driver is described in programmer's manual as below:

```
import iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.*;
...

Module pkcs11Driver;
try {
  pkcs11Driver = Module.getInstance("ca2-v34.dll"); //<--exception!
  pkcs11Driver.initialize(null);

  //test
  System.out.println(pkcs11Driver.getInfo());
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println(ex);
}
```

The exception is raised at the line marked in the code above, with this detail: **java.io.IOException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
ca2-v34.dll**

This exception surely means the IAIK library has found the .dll file, but it is not compatible somehow. I'm being stuck at this bottleneck.

Comment: It looks like `ca2-v34.dll` is a 32-bit DLL.

Comment: the sample usb token manager provided by our manufacturer uses this .dll file for both windows7-32bit and windows7-64bit. i've compared the two files, they are identical, so i believe this dll can be used in both 32bit and 64bit.

Comment: That only means that their software is 32 bit throughout. You can't use a 32-bit DLL from 64 bit software, at least not without building a thunking layer, if that is still possible: we used to have to do that a bit in the 16-32 bit transition.

Comment: thank you. yeah you're right, i have to switch temporarily to jre32 to be able to build and run. i will file a request about getting the 64bit driver dll from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp) in the comments right below the question, **ca2-v34.dll is a 32bit dll**. The sample usb token manager from the manufacturer is a **32bit-throughout software**, so it can load this dll file on both Windows 32 and Windows 64.

The scenario of JRE is different:

- In case the client computer has JRE 32bit installed, the Java application (.jar file) can run well because the process of **JVM is a 32bit process**.
- The other case is that the client computer has JRE 64bit installed, the Java application **can not** run normally because **JVM in this case is a 64bit process**, it can load the Java application (.jar file) but fails to load the file 'ca2-v34.dll' due to a reason that this dll file is 32bit dll.